# Debug asyncio memory leaks

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

How to debug asyncio (with aiohttp) application to find memory leaks?

Application: 100 asyncio coroutines, that read messages from Redis, make some external API http calls, and save results into db.

The problem is here: on bigger messages number (10k-20k) RAM memory used by the application is increasing right after every message.

Doing debugging with objgraph like:

```
print(objgraph.show_growth(limit=100))
```

showed exactly the same result after every new message:

```
weakref                        6163        +4
dict                          19192        +3
builtin_function_or_method     1911        +3
tuple                         16880        +2
function                      25375        +1
method                          496        +1
Event                             8        +1
Condition                         8        +1
deque                            14        +1
SplitResult                      15        +1
Context                          15        +1
Thread                            7        +1
```

Nothing of this is not created by my hands, so this is all third party dependencies.

Also discovered interesting item:
one of the dictionaries (from `show_growth`) is:

```
{'_context': <ssl.SSLContext object at 0x10a4ce228>, 
'_server_side': False, 
'_server_hostname': 
'my.host.name',
'_state': 'SHUTDOWN',
'_incoming': <_ssl.MemoryBIO object at 0x10a620b30>,
'_outgoing': <_ssl.MemoryBIO object at 0x10a620b10>,
'_sslobj': <ssl.SSLObject object at 0x10a664ac8>,
'_need_ssldata': True,
'_handshake_cb': <bound method SSLProtocol._on_handshake_complete of <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x10a664630>>,
'_shutdown_cb': <bound method SSLProtocol._finalize of <asyncio.sslproto.SSLProtocol object at 0x10a664630>>
}
```

As you can see, this is smth like a result of call or response. Is it possible, that all response is here, so it saves every response and RAM is increasing?

How to deal with it?
Or can you advice another approach to find a weak place of app?

Comment: One tool I find useful for tracing memory leaks is [pyrasite](https://github.com/lmacken/pyrasite). You can attach to a running Python process and run a REPL inside. It might be worthwhile to `sys.getsizeof` that specific dictionary to see if it really grows in time. Also make sure that you are using the latest versions of third party libraries, as I saw an earlier version of the Python redis library leaked memory but it got fixed in a later release.

Comment: Thanks. Actually cant install pyrasite, because it is incompatible with python3. Getting size with sys.getsizeof returns nothing interesting, just 100-200 bytes

Answer (score 1):

The growing dictionary is `__dict__` of `_SSLPipe` asyncio internal class.

Would you try [uvloop](https://uvloop.readthedocs.io), Шt is an alternative event loop that has a different SSL transport implementation.

Also, the bug may depend on the used Python version. Did you check on the latest Python (3.8 at the moment)?